# Is it possible to execute event after click in wxPython using wx.toolbar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

Currently I'm working on my Final High school project and I have a serious problem.

I create a wx.Toolbar, add each option using wx.AddTool, and then I bind some functions to it, it does all the stuff only once (at the beginning) and refuses to do anything after clicking on it.. Basically... It starts way earlier than I want to.

I will skip some code, I will only use the needed one.

```
self.frame_toolbar.AddTool(1, "one", Base64ToImg(image1), Base64ToImage(image1-disabled), "One", "First Thing")
self.frame_toolbar.AddTool(2, "two", Base64ToImg(image1), Base64ToImage(image1-disabled), "Two", "Second Thing")
self.frame_toolbar.AddTool(3, "three", Base64ToImg(image1), Base64ToImage(image1-disabled), "Three", "Third Thing")

self.frame_toolbar.Realize()

self.SetToolBar(self.frame_toolbar)
```

So now, I have toolbar with some tools on it. Now:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.onefunction(params), id=1)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.twofunction(params), id=2)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.threefunction(params), id=3)
```

and also

```
self.frame_toolbar.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.onefunction(params), id=1)
self.frame_toolbar.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.twofunction(params), id=2)
self.frame_toolbar.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.threefunction(params), id=3)
```

executes immediately when toolbar loads. Is possible to make it execute **ONLY** when I click on the button?

Thank you so so so much for any help.
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.frame_toolbar.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, lambda evt:self.onefunction(params), id=1)`

I think solves your issue

Comment: Yes.. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the function immediately, `self.onefunction(params)`. Try removing the parenthesis - this will keep it as a function rather than the return of the function

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.onefunction, id=1)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.twofunction, id=2)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.threefunction, id=3)
```

If you need to pass in params, please check Joran's answer

Comment: Oh yeah. Thank you .. I thought that passing parameters directly wont start it itself. So Thank You so much :)

Comment: No worries - If I helped, please upvote this answer so others will be :)